# rs.readFile in async.series sequencing issue

Tags: javascript, node-async

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm not seeing it.

I've reduced my code to the below to illustrate the issue I'm having.

Using `async.series` I'm processing a set of files. for each file, I read it, and do something with the contents, and move on. If I change the `readFile` call to by `readFileSync` I get the expected output, but that's not a solution that is going to work here for a variety of other reasons.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

huh();

function huh() {
    for (var i in [1,2]) {
        async.series([
                function (callback) { process('a', callback); },
                function (callback) { process('b', callback); }
            ], function () { console.log('series done')});
        console.log('done: ' + i);
    }
}

function process(word, callback){
    fs.readFile('whatever', function (err, content) {
        console.log(word);
        callback();
    });
}
```

What I expect when I run the above is:

```
a
b
series done
done: 0
a
b
series done
done: 1
```

But what I get is

```
done: 0
done: 1
a
a
b
series done
b
series done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console.log('done: ' + i); is sync so at first, there is nothing wrong, what u expect is fs.readFileSync， use sync code to match your expect

Comment: unfortunately, as I note in the question, I can't use fs.readFileSync

Comment: ok, then put all into async.series, i will detail in answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');

huh();

function huh() {
  var queue = [];
  for (var i in [1, 2]) {
    (function(tmpi) {
      queue.push(function(callback) {
        process('a', callback);
      });
      queue.push(function(callback) {
        process('b', callback);
      });
      queue.push(function(callback) {
        console.log('series done');
        callback()
      });
      queue.push(function(callback) {
        console.log('done: ' + tmpi);
        callback()
      });

    })(i);




  }
  async.series(queue, function() {
    console.log('all done!')
  });

}

function process(word, callback) {
  fs.readFile('whatever', function(err, content) {
    console.log(word);
    callback();
  });
}
```